# Summing row values by specific columns using mutate_at and sum function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data table with questionnaire data, so the first column is participant IDs followed by columns of each questionnaire headed with the separate questions. for example, the data table would look like this, where `A` is one questionnaire and `B` is a different one:

```
ID A1 A2 A3 B1 B2
1  3  5  3  4  2
2  2  5  2  2  1
3  4  1  3  4  1
4  3  2  3  3  2
```

I want to be coding this using dplyr functions. I'm having trouble using mutate_at from `dplyr` to find the summary scores of each questionnaire, for each `ID`. I want to find the the sum for questionnaire `A` (from `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`), and for `B`...and so on. But my data table has many questionnaires in it (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.....etc) so my code right now looks like:

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("A")), funs(sum)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However running this always gives me an error of

> Error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument

and I can't understand why. Same thing happens when I try `mutate_each`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think one way would be the following. I can see how you want to work with the wide-format data using `mutate_at`, but you may want to choose long format here. That would make your life easy. You can use `melt` or `gather` to format your data in a long format. Then, you want to change the column, `variable`. You want to remove numbers. Finally you group the data by `ID` and `variable` and get sum.

```
melt(mydf, id.var = "ID") %>%
mutate(variable = gsub(pattern = "[0-9]+", replacement = "", x = variable)) %>%
group_by(ID, variable) %>%
summarise(total = sum(value))

#     ID variable total
#  <int>    <chr> <int>
#1     1        A    11
#2     1        B     6
#3     2        A     9
#4     2        B     3
#5     3        A     8
#6     3        B     5
#7     4        A     8
#8     4        B     5
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, A1 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), A2 = c(5L, 5L, 
1L, 2L), A3 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), B1 = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 3L), B2 = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: can you explain what gsub does? also for sum(value), where does the value come from?...

Comment: In the `gsub` I am deleting numbers. For instance, A1 becomes A. If you want to visualize the process, run only two lines like this `melt(mydf, id.var = "ID") %>%mutate(variable = gsub(pattern = "[0-9]+", replacement = "", x = variable))`. Likewise, I recommend you to run just `melt(mydf, id.var = "ID")`. Then, you can see where `variable` and `value` come from. Remind you that you need reshape2 and dplyr packages.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's difficult to do is that you haven't explicitly coded the questionnaire type and number and the data are therefore not "tidy". Jazzurro's approach is right but here I've used the `tidyr` package to do this with `gather` and `separate`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
gather(test, tot, A1:B2) %>% 
separate(test, into=c("Q", "No"), sep=1) %>%
group_by(ID, Q) %>% summarise(totals=sum(tot))
```

This avoids having to use `gsub` and the like.

Also, you can add `%>% spread(Q, totals)` to the end of the pipeline if you want A and B in separate columns.